# Does there exist a subring $R$ of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ such that $A \subsetneq R \subsetneq B$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I was thinking about this problem (all subrings here will refer to subrings that contain $\mathbb{C}$):

> Let $A,B$ be two subrings of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ such that $\operatorname{codim}A+2=\operatorname{codim}B$. Does there exist a subring $R$ of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ such that $A \subsetneq R \subsetneq B$?

It is clear that we can find a subspace that satisfies the condition $A \subsetneq R \subsetneq B$ but it is not clear that it is a subring of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ because it might not be closed with respect to multiplication. I can prove that all the subrings of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ are of the form $\mathbb{C}[f_1,\dots ,f_n]$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$. I am basically stuck at this point and if anyone has any hints or insights it would be appreciated.

Comment: By "codim $A$", I presume you mean the vector-space dimension of ${\mathbb C}[x] / A$?

Comment: Yes, that is the meaning of codim in this case because $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is infinite dimensional.

Comment: One can forget that $B$ is a subring of $\mathbb C[x]$. Write $B=A\oplus \mathbb C e_1 \oplus \mathbb C e_2$. Let $a_{11}, a_{12}, a_{21}, a_{22}, a_{31}, a_{32}\in \mathbb C$ such that $e_1^2\equiv a_{11}e_1+a_{12}e_2$, $e_1e_2\equiv a_{21}e_1+a_{22}e_2$ and $e_2^2\equiv a_{31}e_1+a_{32}e_2$ mod $A$ (as vectors spaces). We are looking for $\lambda, \mu\in \mathbb C$ such that $(e_1+\lambda e_2)^2\equiv \mu (e_1+\lambda e_2)$. This is equivalent to the system $a_{31}\lambda^2+2a_{21}\lambda+a_{11}=\mu$ and $a_{32}\lambda^2+2a_{22}\lambda+a_{12}=\mu\lambda$. Comparing the second equation with

Comment: $\lambda \times$ the first equation, we get $$a_{31}\lambda^3+(2a_{21}-a_{32})\lambda^2+(a_{11}-2a_{22})\lambda-a_{12}=0.$$ If $a_{31}=0$, take $R=A+\mathbb Ce_2$. If $a_{12}=0$, take $R=A+\mathbb C e_1$. Otherwise, there exists a non-zero solution $\lambda\in \mathbb C$. Take $\mu$ given by the first equation. Then $R:=A+\mathbb C (e_1+\lambda e_2)$ answers the question. @user I am hit by the limit of 42 answers, therefore only authorized to post comments.

Comment: I am sorry for not answering earlier but I have been traveling. I think that you are ignoring the ring structure of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ and that is a mistake. Consider for example $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]$ and $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^7]$ are of codimension 1 and 3 respectively. Your reasoning does not seem to be applicable in this case.

Comment: Yes I ignore completely that $A, B$ are subrings of $\mathbb C[x]$ because I think it is irrelevant. My mistake is that $e^2\in A+{\mathbb C}e$ is not enough to insure that $A+{\mathbb C}e$ is a ring. What can you show with your example ? Please add @Cantlog in your answer to make me awared.

Comment: In fact it is easier to consider the more general situation than the codimension $2$ case. If $A\subset B$ are integral $k$-algebras of finite type with $k$ algebraically closed and if $d=\dim_k B/A$ is finite, then for any integer $0\le r\le d$, there exists a subring $A\subseteq R\subseteq B$ such that $\dim B/R=r$. The idea is to consider the conductor ideal $I=\{ a\in A \mid aB\subseteq A\}$. Have you some background in algebraic geometry ?

Comment: @Cantlog The problem is that adding one generator to a subring does not necessarily change its codim by 1. That is why you cannot just ignore the ring structure. Regarding your last comment, I am a beginner in algebraic geometry. Is what you mentioned a theorem or just an easy corollary? If it is possible can you suggest me a good book for algebraic geometry?

Comment: I don't ignore the ring structure, but the hypothesis they are subrings of $\mathbb C[x]$. I don't know whether my claim is a known theorem (probably not important enough to be called so). I am asking for algebraic geometry background because it is easier for me to think about the problem and also to reduce the problem to the case when the conductor ideal $I$ is contained in only one maximal ideal. Suppose for simplicity that $\sqrt{I}$ is a maximal ideal $m_0$ in $A$ and there is only one maximal ideal $m_1$ of $B$ lying over $m_0$. There exists $r\ge 1$ such that $m_1^r\subseteq m_0$

Comment: and $m_1^{r-1}$ not contained in $m_0$. If $r=1$, then $B=A$ and there is nothing to prove. If $r\ge 2$, chose an element $b\in m_1^{r-1}\setminus m_0$ and consider $R=A+kb$. Because $A=k+m_0$, $bm_0\subseteq m_1^r\subseteq A$ and $b^2\in m_1^{2r-2}\subseteq A$, we see that $R$ is a subring of $B$ and $\dim_k R/A=1$.

Comment: If there are at least two maximal ideals $m_1, m_2$ of $B$ lying over $m_0$, consider $R=\{ f\in B \mid f(m_1)=f(m_2)\}$. If $I$ is contained in several maximal ideals of $A$, work locally at one of them, keep intact the other ones, and define $R$ by glueing sheaves of finite algebras (this is why it is easier to use algebraic geometry langage). Without geometry, it is still possible but more complicate.

Comment: @Cantlog, OK thanks. I think I understand now. I will look closely into your last comments. I have something to chew on for a while.